# User attributes not clearing?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm have some trouble with my user model so I added this to it:

```
logout: () ->
    console.log @toJSON()
    @clear()
    console.log @toJSON()
    if @id?
        alert @id
```

**1st: console.log @toJSON()**

```
Object
id: "4e862dc6e69aad002"
#other attributes
__proto__: Object
```

**2nd: console.log @toJSON()**

```
Object
__proto__: Object
```

**But it still alerts the id.. why could this be?**

Comment: i would like to se the toJSON metod plz

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-clear

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-toJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i dont have experience with backbone models but here is whats
happening

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var x = new Model();

x.set({ "id": "hello world" });


alert(x.get("id"));
alert(x.id);
x.clear();
alert(x.id);
alert(x.get("id"));
```

Only the last one is returning undefined
so i asume that .get is the api witch it intends you to use.

I read the source code of backbone and it seams that id is special and thats the only "field"
that it actually puts directly on the object.. and the clear method dos not remove the old value from this.

This seams like a design flaw ... but an id should not change any way right????

I hope this helps Boom

Comment: Ahh, I see, yea you're right. I have to reset the id that is hardset outside of the attributes. If a user has an id my app thinks their logged in so thats why I need to clear it when logging out. Thanks!

Comment: Right, common Backbone mistake: confusing attributes with properties. `clear` resets `@attributes`, and `toJSON` just gives you a clone of `@attributes`; neither has anything to do with `@id` (as opposed to `@attributes.id`).